# AngularJS email validation with Domain checking

Tags: angularjs

I would like to validate email input on AngularJS,I want to add domain check also for e.g. when input is sample@gbail.com to show suggestion user meant to type Gmail...so on.
here's what i use:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="txtmail" ng-pattern="/^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?(\.[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*$/" required  placeholder="sample@domain.com">
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Comment: @georgeawg, Thank you this helped, now I managed to validate @gmail.com based on documentation: /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@gmail\.com$/i        however, i can't validate any other domains now like yahoo.com for e.g.

Comment: @phpguy, check out my answer and try to experiment with the `or` statements I have included in there. If my answer was helpful, please don't forget to upvote or possible accept as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest help is Google's documentation on this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Although I can't think of anything (package wise) that is currently out there that will show suggestions for misspellings on email domains, if you have a list of domains separate you wish to check against, it is possible (through or statements).

**Try to do something like this with your** `ng-pattern`:

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com|msn\.com|hotmail\.com|live\.com)
```

**Or**

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com|msn\.com|hotmail\.com|live\.com)
```

For each new domain email provider, just add it with the `|`

Remember, you can use `or` functionality within your `ng-pattern` too :).

Also, if you say for example, wanted to block an email, just add the negative lookahead `(?!...)`, like so:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!yahoo\.com|gmail\.com|msn\.com|hotmail\.com|live\.com)
```

This will cause anyone who tried to use any of the emails listed above to fail.

Comment: thank you for the reference, now the problem became like even when I type @gnail.com it accept it as far as i can notice all possible domains are permitted with /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@gmail\.com|com|[a-z0-9-]+@yahoo\.com|com$/i

Comment: @phpguy I changed the code example, should be working just fine now :)

Comment: @VolcoMeter, Thank you :) but still, that didn't achieve the results, for e.g. abcd@gail.com is taken as valid email :(

Comment: @phpguy are you adamant about doing this with ng-pattern? You could accomplish the same thing with `blur` with `angularjs`

Comment: @VolcoMeter, i'm noob to AngularJS :) and absolutely open to do it in blur if you can share an example, Thank you

Comment: Hi @VolcoMeter, yes an example would be like is not enough to show that email is not valid, but rather preventing the typo, so the idea will be to implement the feature (correcting the typo). for E.g. user@gnail.com” is a typo and we should prevent it not just display this is invalid email address :)